# VBA Breaking My Formula

Tags: vba, excel

I am using an Add-in called SEOTools for Excel which is free : http://seotools.nielsbosma.se/releases/

VBA is breaking my formula.

```
=Dump(GoogleAnalytics(""ga:1169833"",""ga:adCost,ga:impressions,ga:adClicks,ga:CTR,ga:CPC,ga:goal7Completions"",A307,A306,""ga:campaign"","""",""ga:medium==cpc;ga:campaign!=(not set);ga:campaign!=ZZZ_Old_Mexico"","""",1,10000,FALSE,FALSE))
```

Whats happening is the A307 shows up as 'A307' when the formula is placed into a cell A1 in Excel which does not work for this formula. Why? Can I stop it adding those characters to the cell reference?

Full code  :

```
Worksheets("Latest Time Range").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Dump(GoogleAnalytics(""ga:1169833"",""ga:adCost,ga:impressions,ga:adClicks,ga:CTR,ga:CPC,ga:goal7Completions"",A307,A306,""ga:campaign"","""",""ga:medium==cpc;ga:campaign!=(not set);ga:campaign!=ZZZ_Old_Mexico"","""",1,10000,FALSE,FALSE))"
```

Comment: It would help if you showed us your actual VBA code...

Comment: Are you using the `FormulaR1C1` property by any chance?

Comment: @AmishZ please [edit] that into your original post :)

Comment: Try doing it without the R1C1... just `.Formula`

Answer (score 0):

Your solution relates to your improper use of `FormulaR1C1`.  Rather than using this method, you should just use `.Formula` to insert your formula into the cell.